# Playing back recorded movements with servos

Tags: servo, actuator, best-practice

I'm new to motors/servos so could do with a bit of advice. I'm currently working with 3 Dynamixel servos and it's cool that they can be programmed fairly easily and I can get the current position when torque is disabled. Currently I'm trying to record motions then play them back.

At the moment I have a very basic approach: I record a set of positions over time(multiple times per second) and when I 'playback' the positions, I simply pass the them as the goal positions. The problem is at the moment, with slow position increments I get jerky movement. I imagine it's because I keep setting a new goal position even though some positions are quite close. I imagine it will be more efficient to somehow split a dense list of positions into a some 'key' positions separated over a larger interval of time and only set a new goal position for those 'key' times.

Does this sound reasonable? If so, any hints to what I should into to get started? If not, what ideas are out there? How do people animating robots deal with recording movement and using it?

Comment: Can you be a bit more descriptive about the "jerky movements" and "slow position increments" How slow? What increment? Also, what resolution are the servos? (i.e. the readback position) Do you have a link to them? Posting a relevant snippet of code might help also.

Comment: Any chance you can post a video of the movement to YouTube ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jerky movement is likely caused by the fact that the servo can move fairly fast compared to the rate at which you're sending position commands. If you were to record the movement on a high speed camera, and play it back in slow-mo, what you'd see is the servo moving rapidly towards its target position, and begin to slow down as it reached that position, then finally stop on target.

Then you send it a new target position, and it accelerates quickly up to full speed, then slows down again and stop at the next target.

If you were to record twice as many positions, so that you're sending targets twice as often, then the motor might not have completely stopped before the next target arrives. At which point, it accelerates again. This will produce noticeably smoother movement, because there is less variation in speed (the servo never stops completely).

Double the target rate again, and you'll get smoother movement still. Personally, I suggest sending targets at the highest rate you can. This doesn't mean you need to take more position readings. You can use [linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) (or cubic interpolation, scroll down to the interpolation section on my page about [Perlin Noise](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm)) to increase the number of target positions.

The more often you send target positions, the less the servo's velocity will vary, and the smoother will be its movement.

But, if you're paying attention, you'll notice that each time a new target arrives, the servo hadn't quite reached its previous target. Thus the servo is always late for its targets.

This may not be a problem for you, and it's the normal behaviour of a servo. As long as your're not asking the servo to go faster than it's able to, then it won't be that far behind, and you probably won't notice the error.

---

If you really need the servo to be dead on target all the time. For example, if you are operating a CNC milling machine, and you need to machine metal to an accuracy of 10um, then you need to use a position/velocity control loop which is aware of the list of upcoming target positions, and can control the velocity accordingly. It is probably not possible to do this with a Dynamixel servo.

Comment: I've played with the servos more and read the manual again. It seems don't need to sent to continuous positions. I can pass a servo a 'goal position' and I can read back a parameter to check if it's reached it's goal position or not. Your suggestions area really good, I'll need to spend more time to fully understand Perlin Noise. From what I understand so far, if I move from A to B to C, I shouldn't wait for the 'to B' motion fully complete, but interpolate between A and C so the motor won't stop and start in the middle, correct ?

Comment: If all you want to do is go from A to C, and you don't care how it gets there, then there's certainly no point sending B. But if you're trying to generate a more complex movement profile, then you should update the target as often as possible.

Comment: Forget about Perlin Noise, I was just pointing to the section on interpolation.

Comment: Thanks! You're right. I've increased the update rate and even though the motors can deal with a single instruction of a set goal position, it seems to handle many per frame good so far. Ideally I'd like to simplify the recorded(dense) data based on velocities and smoothly interpolate between the remaining points, but I need to filter out my data properly first and this should be another question :)

Answer (score 2):

Servos are not usually meant to move fast. They offer high torque, and low speed with relative accuracy depending on the application.

I'm guessing it's jerky because you are feeding it *goal* positions too often, and before it reaches a position you have it set to reach, it receives another command to go somewhere else.

You could record the movements more slowly if speed, in fact, is the problem. Or perhaps you could record the movements at a normal pace, and *play it back* at a slower one.

Or else, your key mapping to goal position option seems fine too, it's just that you will be missing the non-key positions - and I don't know how significant they are for what you are trying to do.

Finally, suppose you had goal positions like these:

0 --> 90 --> 180

Throw out the 90 if you are going from 0 to 90 and 90 to 180 at the same pace. Otherwise, it will stop at the 90 and increase the jerkiness. I think you were getting at this, but I just wanted to be more clear.

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down for me, it sounds like this happens to the servos. I'll do a few more tests to get a better understanding of what I'm dealing with.